# Как отобразить код на сайте?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Как отобразить код на сайте? Теги <code></code> и <pre></pre> - не работают. Страницы сайта генерируются php скриптом. Пробовал использовать SyntaxHighlighter - не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте,теги:

```
<xmp></xmp>
```

Если нет,то(вам с подсветкой?,у вас блог,какой?),или тут посмотрите

http://blogomaniy.ru/vedenie-bloga/kakim-obrazom-vyivesti-kodyi-html-php-v-state-svoego-bloga.html

Comment: Спасибо, работает. У меня форум, сам пишу. А как сделать подсветкой?

Comment: Тут,только гуглить)

Answer (score 0):

[здесь](https://github.com/shuvalov-anton/Habralight) я разбирался как работает подсветка на хабре. Они используют вот [эту](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/) библиотеку.